# If any column in a row meets condition than mutate() column

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, conditional-statements

Using dplyr, I am trying to conditionally update values in a column using ifelse and mutate. I am trying to say that, in a data frame, if any variable (column) in a row is equal to 7, then variable c should become 100, otherwise c remains the same.

```
df <- data.frame(a = c(1,2,3),
                 b = c(1,7,3),
                 c = c(5,2,9))

df <- df %>%  mutate(c = ifelse(any(vars(everything()) == 7), 100, c))
```

This gives me the error:

```
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : 
  Evaluation error: (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'double'.
```

The output I'd like is:

```
  a b   c
1 1 1   5
2 2 7 100
3 3 3   9
```

Note: this is an abstract example of a larger data set with more rows and columns.

EDIT:
This code gets me a bit closer, but it does not apply the ifelse statement by each row. Instead, it is changing all values to 100 in column c if 7 is present anywhere in the data frame.

```
df <- df %>%  mutate(c = ifelse(any(select(., everything()) == 7), 100, c))

  a b   c
1 1 1 100
2 2 7 100
3 3 3 100
```

Perhaps this is not possible to do using dplyr?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this should work. We can check if values in `df` equal to 7. After that, use `rowSums` to see if any rows larger than 0, which means there is at least one value is 7.

```
df <- df %>% mutate(c = ifelse(rowSums(df == 7) > 0, 100, c))
```

Or we can use apply

```
df <- df %>% mutate(c = ifelse(apply(df == 7, 1, any), 100, c))
```

A base R equivalent is like this.

```
df$c[apply(df == 7, 1, any)] <- 100
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try with `purrr::map_dbl`

```
library(purrr)
df$c <- map_dbl(1:nrow(df), ~ifelse(any(df[.x,]==7), 100, df[.x,]$c))
```

Output

```
  a b   c
1 1 1   5
2 2 7 100
3 3 3   9
```

In a `dplyr::mutate` statement this would be

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
df %>%
   mutate(c = map_dbl(1:nrow(df), ~ifelse(any(df[.x,]==7), 100, df[.x,]$c)))
```